# Surprising rewriting of URL by htaccess rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've zeroed my problem and I've specific question.

With only the following code in the `.httaccess` why `index2.php` gets called if I type in my URL as `www.mysite.com/url2` ?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.html|.htm|.feed|.pdf|.raw)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index2.php [L]
```

I've also tested it at http://www.regextester.com and should not replace it with index2.php:

[image]

**In the end I want this rule to skip any URL starting with /url2 or /url2/*.**

**EDIT: I've made screen recording of this problem: http://screenr.com/BBBN**

Comment: What is the output of `RewriteLog` ??

Comment: I can't put it in the httpd.conf as I don't have permission to do so.

Comment: What would you like www.mysite.com/url2 to redirect to?  Everything is being routed to index2.php because what you are essentially saying is take all pages (delineated by '(.*)') and forward traffic to 'index2.php'.

Comment: I want anything like /url2/* to be skipped by above rule. But it is rewriting to index2.php

Comment: I think you should clear the .htaccess file. Then try again.

Comment: This rule should not match your url. What happens if you rename `index2.php` to `asdfasdf.php` and alter your rule, does it still rewrite `/url2` to that?

Comment: @Sumurai8 I've changed it to asdfasdf.php in .htaccess and renamed index2.php to asdfasdf.php then also asdfasdf.php is getting called indeed

Comment: Changes are gettingg reflected immediately.

Comment: @Sumurai8 I forgot to add that if I delete asdfasdf.php it shows 404 page not found. When it is there it runs and prints that unable to connect to database.

Comment: @AgA `__FILE__` gives the path to the php file that is executed (but we already knew what file was executed). The real question is what the original url is rewritten to that prompts causes your rewriterule to match. Have you tried my answer? If you look at the error message that is displayed when a 404 happens, you see that `ErrorDocument` is defined, but a 404 as well (probably in httpd.conf). Therefore the second part of undone's answer might work.

Comment: @Sumurai8  pl. check my comments in Undone's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.html|.htm|.feed|.pdf|.raw)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index2.php [L]
```

What it does? it rewrites anything that ends with **html**, **htm**, **feed** , **pdf** , **raw**  to `index2.php`. So, if you are getting results as your URL is ends with those extensions, then there are two possible answers:

1. There is another rewrite rule in an `.htaccess` in upper directories (or in server config files) that causes the URL to be rewritten.
2. Your URL actually ends with those extensions. have in mind, what you enter in your address bar, will be edited and rewritten. For example, if you enter `www.mysite.com/url2` in your address bar and that file doesn't exist on server, your server will try to load the proper error document. So, if your error document is `/404.html`, it will be rewritten to `index2.php`  at the end.

---

**Update**:
I think it's the case. create a file named `404.php`  in your document root. Inside your main `.htaccess` (in your document root), put this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

delete all other `ErrorDocument`  directives.
inside `404.php`  , put this:

```
<?php
    echo 'From 404.php file';
?>
```

---

**Logic behind it:**

When you have a weird behavior in mod_rewrite, the best solution in my experience is using rewrite log.  to enable rewrite log put this in your `virtualhost` or other server config directives you may choose:

```
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteLog "logs/RewriteLog.log"
```

**be careful**: the code above will enable rewrite log and start logging at highest level possible (logging everything). It will decrease your server speed and the log file will become huge very quickly. Do this only on your dev server.

**Explanation**: When you try to access `www.mysite.com/url2`, Apache gives your URL to rewrite module. Rewrite module checks if any of `RewriteRule`s applies to your URL. Because you have one rule and it doesn't apply to your URL, it tries to load the normal file. But this file does not exit. So, Apache will do the next step which is showing the proper error message. When you set a custom error file, Apache will run the test against the new address. For example if error document is **/404.html**, Apache checks whether your rule applies to **/404.html** or not. Since it does, it will rewrite it.

The point to remember is apache will do this every time there is change in URL, whether the change is made by rewrite module or not!

Comment: I've made screen recording here: http://screenr.com/BBBN . I don't think your points are applicable.

Comment: Do what I said in updated part and let me know what happens. the reason I'm sure what I said is the reason is because after you renamed your file (the one was like `asas...`) , You received `404` error. but notice that at the bottom of the page, it says it couldn't access the file that was set to be used for 404 errors!

Comment: I've many other sites running .. will it affect them if I put this in public_html?

Comment: If they have the same document root, yes. otherwise no!

Comment: I've done as per you've asked in "Update", now /url2 is outputting : "From 404.php file". Can you please add references of this logic? I'll access your answer .. Thanks .. this must be the puzzle of the year.

Comment: @AgA That is the behaviour you would expect. You request a file `/url2` on the server. The server says: "Hey, that file doesn't exist.". It then says "Hey! If a file doesn't exist, I should show 404.php". It then outputs your custom 404 page. Previously it was: "Hey, that file doesn't exist." -> "Hey! I should show 404.html" -> "Hey, if a file ends on .html, I should rewrite it to `index2.php`" (which is not what you wanted)

Comment: @AgA  i added the explanation!

Comment: But why'd this rewrite not happen when we define the ErrorDocument?

Comment: because as you can see, it ends with **.php**, so rewrite rule doesn't apply here!

Answer (score 0):

The rule you list [should work as you expect](http://www.screenr.com/x7BN) if this is the only rule. Fact is that theory is fun, but apparently it doesn't work as expected. Please note that `.` will match ANY CHARACTER. If you want to match the full stop/period character, you'll need to escape it. That's why I use `\.(html|htm|feed|pdf|raw)$` instead of `(.html|.htm|.feed|.pdf|.raw)$` below.

---

You can add another `RewriteCond` that simply doesn't match if the url starts with /url2, like below. This might not be a viable solution if there are lots of urls that shouldn't be matched.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/url2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(html|htm|feed|pdf|raw)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index2.php [L]
```

---

To get a better understanding of what is happening you can alter the rule to something like this. Now simply enter the urls you dont want to be matched in the url bar and inspect the url bar after the redirect happens. In the url-parameter you now see what url actually triggered this rule to match. [This screencast](http://www.screenr.com/R7BN) shows you a similar version working with a sneaky rewriterule that is working away on the url.

```
#A way of finding out what is -actually- matched
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(html|htm|feed|pdf|raw)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/foo
RewriteRule (.*) /foo?url=$1 [R,L]
```

---

You can decide to match the `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable instead. This will always contain the request itself. If something else is rewriting the url, this variable doesn't change, meaning you can use this to overwrite any changes. Make sure the url won't be matching itself. You would get something like below. An example screencast can be found [here](http://www.screenr.com/O7BN).

```
#If it doesn't end on .html/htm/feed etc, this one won't match
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /.*\.(html|htm|feed|pdf|raw)\ HTTP [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index2\.php$
RewriteRule (.*) /index2.php [L]
```